# ?: Conditional Operator in LINQ not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I'm having problems with one of my LINQ queries, so I made a simplified version of it in LINQPad to help me. Problem is, I don't understand why it's still not doing what I think it should...

```
var list = "1 2 3 4".Split();
var result = list.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                    x == "3"
                    && true);
result.Dump();
```

This gives back `3`, just like one would assume.
However, when I run this:

```
var list = "1 2 3 4".Split();
var result = list.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                    x == "3"
                    && false ? false : true);
```

I get `1` back. The last line is the simplification of the actual code. Both examples should give `true` on the last line, which would return `3`, but the query with the conditional operator is throwing a kink in there.

What am I missing?

Comment: +1: Upon initially reading the question, I furrowed my brow and wondered, "What am I missing? Why would you expect to get 1 out of the second example? `x == "3" && false` always evaluates to false..." Failing to think about operator precedence can cut both ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your test expression is associating like this:

```
(x == "3" && false) ? false : true
```

instead of like this:

```
x == "3" && (false ? false : true)
```

Comment: Wow. This is CS101. I'm ashamed. Thank you.

Comment: @G_M C-dialect 101. Operator precedence varies by language.

Comment: @Mystere Man - I did. I had to wait 10 minutes before it would let me though!

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is due to operator precedence. A fix for you would be to wrap the condition in parens:

```
x == "3" && (false ? false : true)
```

&& has a higher precedence than ?:

Answer (score 1):

it counts as `(x == "3" && false) ? false : true` which is why you have a strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your lambda evaluates to `(x == 3 && false) ? false : true` which will return the first element because the condition will always evaluate to false. Put parentheses for clearer code.